# Multiple aggregations in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to do multiple aggregations in Spark Structured Streaming.

Something like this:

- Read a stream of input files (from a folder)
- Perform aggregation 1 (with some transformations)
- Perform aggregation 2 (and more transformations)

When I run this in Structured Streaming, it gives me an error "Multiple streaming aggregations are not supported with streaming DataFrames/Datasets".

Is there a way to do such multiple aggregations in Structured Streaming?

Comment: Have you tried using the lower level `DStream` abstraction?

Comment: I was hoping to use structured streaming (datasets / dataframes). Can you point me to some example where something similar is done with DStream?

Comment: any work around on this issue? please provide..same issue here

Comment: Workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011002/multiple-aggregations-in-spark-structured-streaming/60425223#60425223

Answer (score 17):

This is not supported, but there are other ways also. Like performing single aggregation and saving it to kafka.  Read it from kafka and apply aggregation again. This has worked for me.

Comment: I have been trying to solve a similar problem this way but I am having some trouble verifying behaviour. If I have two applications, one producing the first aggregated stream (output in update mode) and the second reading the stream and performing the second aggregation; will the second application continually get the updated values from the first application?

Comment: You may want to consider that writing to Kafka in Spark is NOT exactly-once. (Stateful exactly-once and end-to-end exactly-once are different.) You could get duplicates in your output topics, and it might make second aggregation being incorrect. This approach should have to be executed with "end-to-end" exactly-once.

Comment: @JungtaekLim, thanks when we tested it, we didn't get any duplicates when we implemented it

Comment: It would provide duplicate if one of partition fails to write where other partitions succeed to write, and finally such batch is failed. Sure in happy case duplicates will not happen.

Answer (score 6):

As in Spark 2.4.4 (latest for now) is NOT support the Multiple streaming aggregations you can use the .foreachBatch() [method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch)

A dummy example:

```
query =  spark
        .readStream
        .format('kafka')
        .option(..)
        .load()

       .writeStream
       .trigger(processingTime='x seconds')
       .outputMode('append')
       .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function)
       .start()

query.awaitTermination()        


def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
     # Transformations (many aggregations)
     pass
```

Comment: Worth noting a streaming aggregation can carry state across micro-batches. When those micro-batches are exposed as non-streaming datasets and iterated in foreachBatch you cannot carry state across datasets e.g. with flatMapGroupsWithState you get clean GroupState for each iteration

Answer (score 3):

Multiple aggregates in Spark Structured streaming is not supported as of Spark 2.4. Supporting this can be tricky esp. with event time in "update" mode since the aggregate output could change with late events. Its much straightforward to support this in "append" mode however spark does not support true watermarks yet.

Heres a proposal to add it in "append" mode - https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23576

If interested you can watch the PR and post your votes there.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR - this is not supported; in some cases workarounds are possible.

Longer version -

1. (a hack)

In some cases workarounds are possible, for example, if you'd like to have multiple `count(distinct)` in a streaming query on a low-cardinality columns, then it's easy for `approx_count_distinct` to actually return *exact* number of distinct elements by putting `rsd` argument low enough (that's the 2nd optional argument for approx_count_distinct, by default that's `0.05`).

How is "low-cardinality" defined here? I don't recommend to rely on this approach for columns that can have more than 1000 unique values.

So in your streaming query you can do something like this -

```
(spark.readStream....
      .groupBy("site_id")
      .agg(approx_count_distinct("domain", 0.001).alias("distinct_domains")
         , approx_count_distinct("country", 0.001).alias("distinct_countries")
         , approx_count_distinct("language", 0.001).alias("distinct_languages")
      )
  )
```

Here's proof it actually works:

[image]

Notice that count(distinct) and `count_approx_distinct` give the same results!
Here's some guidance on `rsd` argument `count_approx_distinct`:

- for a column with 100 distinct values `rsd` of **0.02** was necessary;
- for a column with 1000 distinct values `rsd` of **0.001** was necessary.

PS. Also notice that I had to comment out the experiment on a column with 10k distinct values as I didn't have enough patience for that to complete. That's why I mentioned you should not use this hack for columns with over 1k distinct values. For `approx_count_distinct` to match exact count(distinct) on over 1k distinct values would require `rsd` way too low for what [HyperLogLogPlusPlus algorithm](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/10edeafc69250afef8c71ed7b3c77992f67aa4ff/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/HyperLogLogPlusPlus.scala) was designed for (this algorithm is behind approx_count_distinct implementation).

2. (nice but more involving way)

As somebody else mentioned, you can use Spark's [arbitrary stateful streaming](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html) to implement your own aggregates; and as many of aggregations as necessary on a single stream using [[flat]MapWithGroupState](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/GroupState.html). And this would a legit and supported way to do it unlike the above hack that only works in some cases. This method is only available for Spark Scala API and not available for PySpark.

3. (perhaps this will be a long-term solution one day)

A proper way be to show some support for native multiple aggregation in Spark Streaming - https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23576 -- vote up on this SPARK jira/ PR and show your support if you're interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Spark 2.0 since the Structured Streaming API is still experimental. Refer [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations) to see a list of all current limitations.

Comment: I am checking this out. I guess it will work. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is the way to go for now due to lack of support in the structured streaming API.

Answer (score 0):

For spark 2.2 and above (not sure about earlier version), if you can design the aggregation to use **flatMapGroupWithState** with *append* mode, you can do as many aggregations as you want.
The restriction is mentioned here [Spark structured streaming - Output mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any code so I'm going with the example code referencing [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets).

Let's suppose that below is our initial code for DF to use.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
spark = SparkSession. ...

# Read text from socket
socketDF = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 9999) \
    .load()

socketDF.isStreaming()    # Returns True for DataFrames that have streaming sources

socketDF.printSchema()

# Read all the csv files written atomically in a directory
userSchema = StructType().add("name", "string").add("age", "integer")
csvDF = spark \
    .readStream \
    .option("sep", ";") \
    .schema(userSchema) \
    .csv("/path/to/directory")  # Equivalent to format("csv").load("/path/to/directory")
```

Here group df by **name** and apply aggregation functions **count**, **sum** and **balance**.

```
grouped = csvDF.groupBy("name").agg(F.count("name"), F.sum("age"), F.avg("age"))
```

Comment: can you please explain how can i write dataframe "grouped "  into a hive table ?

Comment: If I do `df_joined.writeStream.queryName('joined_query').outputMode('complete').format('memory').start()`, I get the same error in the first question: `Multiple streaming aggregations are not supported with streaming DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

As of spark structured streaming 2.4.5, multiple aggregations are not supported in stateless processing.
But it is possible to aggregate multiple times if you need stateful processing.

With append mode, you can use `flatMapGroupWithState` API on a grouped dataset (obtained by using `groupByKey` API) multiple times.