# Spark Structured Streaming chaining aggregations

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

When I have multiple stages of aggregations, each stage use output of last stage as input, I know its not supported yet as far as spark 2.3.2, what`s your work around?

Comment: I know one way is to store output of last stage into Kafka, then readstream from Kafka and do the next stage, but what a huge waste of Serializations/Deserializations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple aggregations in Spark Structured Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011002/multiple-aggregations-in-spark-structured-streaming)