# Why Multiple transformations of DataFrame(with multiple operations like Joins,Groupby etc) in Structured Streaming is not allowed?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

We have a requirement where two incoming DataSet/DataFrame needs to go through multiple operations (like join, groupby, etc)  to reach to a final state.

For example, the incoming dataframes are `df1` and `df2`:

```
df3 = df1.groupby("key")
df4 = df3.join(df2)
...
```

Lets say that finally `df7` is the dataframe that I need to send to `writeStream`.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to achieve this in Structured Streaming?
2. What is the major reason to not support this in straightforward manner?

PS: I came across this question and a possible solution using `flatMapGroupWithState`: [Multiple aggregations in Spark Structured Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011002/multiple-aggregations-in-spark-structured-streaming).
Can you please give an example how can the above scenario be done using `flatMapGroupWithState` for my first question and my second question is not part of the link above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A join is allowed, so I cannot follow it really.

Comment: We have multiple joins and groupby  . Basically multiple transformations on a dataframe. I just added ... at the end indicating that.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking as some things are allowed in some output modes and not others. For 15 pts a heck of a lot.

Comment: In both output or append mode right now a dataframe is not allowed to have multiple aggregations if you refer the link i attached

Comment: what i want is to do chain of transformations of a dataframe and then send it to sink with update or append mode

Comment: Clear, so why ask a question on something that is not allowed as per the latest Sp Str Str manual? The title to your question should change if you want flatMapG...otherwise the answer is simply not allowed

Comment: important question is the reason behind not allowin it. to understand better . thats the question title . i want to understand why its not allowed as it was allowed in Spark streaming. I have asked the 2 questions clearly in the body too